# Cakephp command stops after migration

Tags: php, cakephp, command-line

I'm running a site with cakephp 
A link is executing this command :

```
define('SHELL_COMMAND_LINE', 'cd ~/public_html/results/lib/Cake/Console/; ./cake AddUserAnalyses -app ~/public_html/results/app');
```

It works well on the old shared hosting : PHP Version 5.3.29

On the new one vps: PHP Version 5.6.26 
when clicking the link the page keeps loading loading ...

The host told me that it's maybe a timeout !!

Important :
When the same command is executed with putty ssh or with a cronjobs it woks fine
Any help please?